# Can certain exercises help with flexbility?

Tags: weightlifting, stretching, flexibility, weights

Rather than simply just stretching, can exercises help to improve flexibility too?

So two examples I'm thinking of are:

1. Romanian deadlifts to improve hamstring flexibility
2. Chest flys to improve chest flexibility

These are two areas that are very tight for me, and I feel like doing stretches only gets me so far... when I do exercises like the above, I does feel like I'm getting a good stretch as I'm doing them, but I may just be imagining it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, full range of motion resistance training can increase flexibility.

[Morton, S. K., Whitehead, J. R., Brinkert, R. H., & Caine, D. J. (2011). Resistance Training vs. Static Stretching: Effects on Flexibility and Strength. Journal of Strength and Conditioning Research, 25(12), 3391–3398. https://doi.org/10.1519/jsc.0b013e31821624aa](https://doi.org/10.1519/jsc.0b013e31821624aa)

[Leite, T. B., Costa, P. B., Leite, R. D., Novaes, J. S., Fleck, S. J., & Simão, R. (2017). Effects of Different Number of Sets of Resistance Training on Flexibility. International journal of exercise science, 10(3), 354–364.](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/28966703/)

[Santos, E., Rhea, M. R., Simão, R., Dias, I., de Salles, B. F., Novaes, J., Leite, T., Blair, J. C., & Bunker, D. J. (2010). Influence of Moderately Intense Strength Training on Flexibility in Sedentary Young Women. Journal of Strength and Conditioning Research, 24(11), 3144–3149. https://doi.org/10.1519/jsc.0b013e3181e38027](https://doi.org/10.1519/jsc.0b013e3181e38027)